# I can't migrate for some reason in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Migration files in laravel is used to create the tables in the database, right? But when ever I try to migrate it gives me this error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app>php artisan migrate
>
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (
>     `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
>     `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim
>     estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

---

and I created a new migration file and it's called test. I know users already exist but I want to create the new table I created which is called test. I dropped all my tables and re-migrate it but it only created my users and migration table again. Not the new table I wanted to create which is test.

here is the migration file i am going to use to create my table but wont create:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tests');
    }
}
```

here is the users migration file that tells me it exist:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

here is the password migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```

here is the dummies migration file I also wanted to create but wont create for some reason even after i drop the all the tables:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDummiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dummies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamp('date'); //if you dont put name for the timestamp it will create: create_at and update_at fields.
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dummies');
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason you would ever get that error is if your migration tries to create a table called users, when a table called users already exists. There is no other reason that error would be thrown. Drop the entire db, recreate it and run the migration again.

Comment: could you paste all your migrations filenames?

Comment: @joe i dropped the entire db and re migrated again and it only created my users table and migrations table not my new tables that i wanted to create which is test and dummies. Why?

Comment: @lami, paste the migration filenames, because your problem is that some of them are not executed.

Comment: have you tried running `composer dump` before running your migration?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this command ? `php artisan migrate:refresh`

If you do then try this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And do the same thing in your others migrations files , that way, the table will be drop before every migration and you not have your problem anymore :)
(it is quite the same thing as a `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

first remove tests, users, password_resets, dummies from migrations table in your database after then run `php artisan migrate` command